Help identifying this Freeagent bike?
so I’m considering the purchase of this bike but all the information about it provided is that it is a Freeagent bike. There are asking $150 and depending on the model/year that may or may not be a good price. Luckily this frame looks distinctive but i still have not been able to figure out exactly which model it is. To me it looks like its a racing bike but I’m not even exactly certain that is the case, can anyone recognize or pinpoint the model? Notice the welding in the front of the frame. I also can notice that it has a one piece crank system which its safe to say is probably original (since i don’t imagine someone would replace a 3 piece with a one piece)


Do you need a bike to ride?  Or is this an "investment" or collecting ?

@Criggie Investment lol

so what's your goal?   Transport or something else ?   We can't do "valuations" here

I’m not looking for a valuation, I thought it was pretty clear that I would just like some help in identifying which model this freeagent is, but to be more clear I would like to know the year of the bike as well as the freeagent line it comes from. So really my goals related to the bikes purchase aren’t relevant unless we’re just small-talking here

Based on eyeballing bmxmuseum.com, I'd guess a 2003 Raceway.
